# How to sets the process title in Go?

Tags: go

How to sets the process title in Go? 
Such as node.js

```
process.title=""
```

Comment: Why **"powershell"** and **"cmd"** tags?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any currently. As its implementation would be OS dependent. Nodejs did it through libuv which on linux, it uses prctl syscall with PR_SET_NAME see [source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8485a7c0b71fd1dd36947a6dd02b75387805d9b7/deps/uv/src/unix/linux-core.c#L947).

You can accomplish the same result using the syscall package. And make sure you suffix your go source code with _linux as it would be OS dependant code.

Similar question with answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926020/setting-process-name-as-seen-by-ps-in-go)

Comment: I see.Thank you user658991.